# Using SLIMV to code Lisp, how do I insert a single " without disabling paredit.vim?

Tags: vim, lisp, common-lisp, paredit, vimclojure

I need to write the following line of code:

```
((eq item #\") (do-this...))
```

But everytime I type ", I get "".  I've read the paredit.vim doc file but it's not clear how to insert a single pair character (be it ", (, or [), and whether doing it breaks paredit for that function.  Any experts have a way around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the author of Slimv. I have fixed this problem, so after \ the " character is not doubled. Please fetch the latest paredit.vim from the Slimv repository: https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv/

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  One more thought, would it make sense to do the same for the paren () and bracket [] characters too?  I haven't yet needed to escape them in code the same way, probably even more of an edge case, but maybe useful nonetheless?

Comment: Yes, you are right, so I have added the same handling for escaped () and [] characters as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Type `,(` to toggle the paredit mode in SLIMV before typing the character.** Source: [slimv.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/slimv.vim/blob/master/ftplugin/slimv.vim).

Similar in emacs, where you can use `C-q` followed by the character to insert a single pair character literally without activating the paredit key it is bound to. Source: [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit).

Comment: In most terminals you have to use `<C-v>` instead of `<C-q>` because `<C-q>` means «continue» there (with `<C-s>` meaning «stop updating terminal window with new output»).